# how to fix Unresolved reference: packageManager in DialogFragment

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to make a call from DialogFragment but the (packageManager) doesn't accept
how to solve it?!

```
class ItemDetkFragment : DialogFragment() {

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val v: View= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_detk, container, false)

    v.car_typee.text= car_item.type
    v.item_typee.text= car_item.item_type
    v.modele.text= car_item.modele
    v.pricee.text= car_item.price+ " JD"

    if (car_item.number> 0) {
        v.numberr.text= "available"
        v.numberr.setTextColor(Color.GREEN)

    } else {
        v.numberr.text= "Not available"
        v.numberr.setTextColor(Color.RED)

    }

    Picasso.with(activity).load(car_item.picUrl).into(v.photo)

    v.contactPhone.setOnClickListener {

        val phoneNum = "855394839583"// the number for testing
        val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL)
        i.data = Uri.parse("tel:$phoneNum")

        if (i.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) { //the 
       problem is here in (((((packageManager)))))it is in red!!!
            startActivity(i)
        }

    }

    return v
}


}
```

[image: my code in picture]

as you can see from the picture the (packageManager) is in red, how to fix it!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
PackageManager packageManager = getActivity().getPackageManager();
if (i.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
    startActivity(i)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your code `packageManager` isn't defined as a variable, instead change it to `getPackageManager()`

So it becomes

```
if (i.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) { 
        startActivity(i)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I noticed Android Studio only seems to have this problem when using `Fragment`s. Consider using a `MainPage` instead. All the same, I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**
package manger requires an activity to access it, if you are using fragment then just refer to the parent context, which the activity that the fragment is associated with.

Like this :

```
 if (i.resolveActivity(context.packageManger) != null) { 
        startActivity(i)
}
```